# Restricting inputs in html form elements

Tags: html, validation

I have a form which contains a textbox. i want the textbox to accept only three numbers i.e. 1, 3 or 6. How can i apply such a validation at the client side.

```
<input type="number" name="NumberOfDays" min="1" />
```

Comment: You can try using Regex.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Can you please help with the expression?

Comment: Please see the answer. Try to submit the form with anything other than 1 or 3 or 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RegEx pattern, you can validate the input. The input will not accept anything other than `1` or `3` or `6`. Try adding some value and submitting it. And remove the `type="number"`, if you are using `pattern`.

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="[1|3|6]{1}" name="NumberOfDays" min="1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @NisargShah Try now? It was because of having `type="number"`.

Comment: Works fine! It's pretty neat actually. I was thinking along the lines of `keydown` combined with `preventDefault`.

Comment: @NisargShah Thanks man... Most of the problems have a simple solution like this.